# Override Anchor color to inherit the default color

Tags: css, inheritance

I'm trying to override the anchor color and set the color to be what it normally would have been without the link.

```css
a .right {
    color:inherit;
}
a:link .right {
    color:inherit;
}
```

```html
<a href="...">
    <div class="right">
        <div class="text">
            Some Text
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

Neither seem to be working.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put a class on the anchor itself and then set:

```
.yourAnchorClass { color: inherit; }
```

[See fiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/PN2Pj/2/)

Inheritance is from the *parent* element. So all your solutions are doing is telling the `div`s to inherit the color of the anchor. By the way, it is actually invalid HTML4 to have a `div` inside an `a` tag (a block level element inside an inline element). If you can, it would be best to change those to `span` and then set `display: block` on the span elements inside the `a`.

Comment: You might also want to set `.yourAnchorClass:visited` (and perhaps even `:hover` and `:active` if applicable) to the same value.